# Duplicate request with `Sec-Fetch-User: ?1` header messes up my request throttling

Tags: request, http-headers, chromium, w3c

I have a web site and I have implemented my own request throttling for extra security.

The problem is that, from one particular machine, I get duplicate requests, almost identical between them. The two requests are generated with millisecond time-difference between them.

The original request is executed when some JavaScript code submits a form programmatically.

The only difference between them is that the first request has this header defined:

`Sec-Fetch-User: ?1`

Based on [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/#sec-fetch-user-header) page, it seems that the header means that the 1st request was NOT generated by a user?

The text is quite technical and I could not drill down much into what this `?1` means.

Can anyone enlighten me? Does it mean that it was generated by a tool and that I can simply deny to serve requests with that header?

Also, this seems to happen from any browser on the device (Win10 OS). Any idea what kind of software is doing this and why?

**UPDATE:**

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493100/testing-with-watir-chromedriver-failed-with-sec-fetch-user-in-request-headers) question, I tried tested with non-Chromium-based browsers on the same machine and I have the impression that it is not happening on those browsers.

But I wonder why this happens mostly on this particular machine and what is the meaning of this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found into this [IETF draft](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-header-structure.html#boolean), `?1` actually means `true`. So the first request you observe is likely being triggered by the user (when submitting the form), and the second one isn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It turns out that the problem was simple, just the inconsistent behavior across devices and across browsers scared me. We were handling the form submission button-click to issue the request to the server programmatically, but we forgot doing a `event.preventDefault()`. So, it makes sense to have duplicate requests. The question is why we don't get the same behavior in all browsers and in all PCs. That is mind-boggling... Anyway, the problem is solved now! :)

Comment: Well, probably something missing in the W3C spec, or something badly implemented by the browsers. Anyway, you're welcome!